# Comparing a char value with an object

Tags: java, string

In Java, the `pop()` function returns the popped out value in the form of an object.

I converted the object into a `String` using the `.toString()` method. I have a character which I converted into a `String`. Now my question is that if I compare the two Strings, will they be equal or not?

Example: (Assume that I already had some values in the stack)

```
Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<>();
Character c=stack.pop();
//let the returned value is : a
String a=c.toString();
String b=Character.toString('a');
```

Now if I compare the two Strings as:

```
if(a.equals(b)){System.out.println("same");}
```

Will the condition becomes true?

Comment: This condition will be true whenever the letter `a` is popped off the top of the stack.  Have you tried running this code yourself?

Comment: of course they will... Because the equals method compares the value of your variables...

Comment: Have you considered testing the characters for equality directly? Converting both to a `String` will work, but it will be *less* efficient.

Comment: Though I have answered , it is quite obvious for you to run and see whether it works .

Comment: Please do not edit your question to include a new problem. Instead, create a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Ofcourse it does , but this is neither an efficient way nor a recommended way to find out whether top of stack is same as given character

Try this

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class test
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<>();
        stack.push('a');
        Character c=stack.pop();
        if(c.compareTo('a')==0)
            System.out.println("same");
    }
}
```

Explanation :   `Character` class of java implements the `Comparable` interface . Hence you can compare the objects of Character class directly

or

you can do something as simple as this

```
import java.util.Stack;

    public class test
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Stack<Character> stack=new Stack<>();
            stack.push('a');
            Character c=stack.pop();
            if(c=='a')
                System.out.println("same");
        }
    }
```

Explanation :  `Character` object is [un-boxed](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) and converted to primitive character type

Comment: Thanks for the help! I tried running the program but the compareTo() always results in a negative number.

Comment: Did you run the above code?  I posted them after testing and they work fine